# I'm not sure how to structure my arithmetic methods

Tags: java

I'm kind of new to Java. I want a method that will use submethods(?). I want something like this:

```
Math.Addition(1, 1, X in this case, integer of users choice for the output);
```

The output would be stored in the variable X. But I also want to do something like this:

```
Math.Subtraction(2, 1, X);
```

How would I do this?

Comment: It seems like you want the user to be able to type in some language expressions, and using parsing techniques, evaluate them...

Comment: It looks like you want out parameters, that's not generally possible in Java. `Integer` objects (or objects of other wrapper classes for primitive types) are immutable, so it won't work for those. You can use classes with mutator-methods as out parameters, though. But it's better to return the results, as usual.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class called Math.

and Have two methods inside it named 'Addition' and 'Subtraction' with required arguments and put the logic for each inside the method.

```
public class Math {
public static int X; 
public static int Addition(int a, int b, String choice) {
    X = a+b;
    return X;
}

public static int Substraction(int a, int b, String choice) {
    X = a-b;
    return X;
}

}
```

Comment: It seems that the methods should be static.
The method structure you are using is not very Java-like, however.
Instead of `Math.addition(1,1,X);` it would better to write `X = Math.addition(1,1);`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to return the value in order to assign to x.  e.g.

X = myClass.add(1,1);